# Symfony2 Routing: how to don't omit default parameters automatically

Tags: php, symfony, routes

If I define a route like this one:

```
search:
    path:     /search/{country}/{xxx}-3-{xxxId}/{page}/{limit}
    defaults: 
        _controller: SearchBundle:Search:index
        page: 0
        limit: 8
```

it will omit the {page} and {limit}-Parameters if they are passed with their default parameters.

Building a route with page=2 and limit=4 will return

```
/search/country/xxx-3-xxxId/2/4
```

But when {limit} is passed with 8, it will return

```
/search/country/xxx-3-xxxId/2
```

instead of

```
/search/country/xxx-3-xxxId/2/8
```

Is their a way to prevent, that parameters are omitted automatically if they equals their defined defaults?

Comment: Just don't set default `limit`, why you set default if you not need it?

Comment: The only reason is to let the URL for the first page to "/search/country/xxx-3-xxxId" without any page and limit. But from the second page on there should be always the page and always the limit in the url

Comment: I see, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define many routes to the same action:

```
search_main:
    path: /search/{country}/{xxx}-3-{xxxId}
    defaults: 
        _controller: SearchBundle:Search:index

search:
    path: /search/{country}/{xxx}-3-{xxxId}/{page}/{limit}
    defaults: 
        _controller: SearchBundle:Search:index
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function indexAction($country, $xxx, $xxxId, $page = 0, $limit = 8)
{
}
```